# Define order of sort options

Tags: catalog, sorting

Currently my list of options to Order the results on the Category page are: position, name, price, color & newest.

I can't find the option (and Google doens't help me either) to place price as the first option in this list. So it's about the  showing the sort options.

I can change the toolbar.phtml file and adjust the sorting in there on the frontend myself, but I assume there must be a more elegant way of adjusting this in the code. Anyone has a suggestion to help me on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old, but I wanted to share this anyway. For whomever that might find it useful.

To expand on David Manners' second and third method, this is how I solved it. Add this to `toolbar.phtml`:

```
$availableOrders = array(
    'name' => 'Naam',
    'price' => 'Prijs',
    'position' => 'Nieuwste'
);
$this->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders);
```

Answer (score 1):

These fields are created by the function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray` so to change these you have a couple of options.

**Rewrite Mage_Catalog_Model_Config**

Nice and simple here rewrite the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config` and change the function `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray` to do what you need. Or better yet dispatch your own before and after events and then create an observer that manipulates the orders.

**Change the toolbar template**

The toolbar uses the template `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` technically you could change the template used and display the options how you want.

**Use the setAvailableOrders function**

Now the toolbar block has a function setAvailableOrders so what you could do is simply call this function and set the orders that you want. It takes and array of attribute and label.

```
array(
    'attribute_1' => 'Label 1',
    'attribute_2' => 'Label 2'
)
```